# hood.ie Start takes long time

Tags: javascript, hoodie

Whenever I start my new hood.ie app (by going to the path, and entering `hoodie start`), the browser appears with my index page however a certain network resource takes > 30 seconds to load (the browser spinner keeps going).

I checked in Chromes inspector tools and it is hoodie.js that takes 1.1. mins to load.

Its the Waiting (TTFB) thats 57 seconds.

Any idea on how I can speed this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue, that will be resolved in the upcoming version, that we are currently working on now. Best is to follow Hoodie on Twitter https://twitter.com/hoodiehq and/or to subscribe to our newsletter to stay up to date with its development: http://hood.ie/

Comment: Cool - thanks!
Any idea on roughly when this fix is expected?

Comment: I can't really tell yet, it's not only a fix, it's a new version, rebuild from the ground up. I'd check in in January again.

Comment: But also make sure you have the latest hoodie-server version, it's 4.0.3